# 'setDate' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors

I'm trying to add a current time feature to my website and I ran into a problem with my code. When I run my code, it fails to compile, but when you inspect the page you can see the time being displayed. Here's my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const DateTime = () => {

var [date,setDate] = useState(new Date());

useEffect(() => {

    var timer = setInterval(()=>setDate(new Date()), 1000 )

    return function cleanup() {
        clearInterval(timer)
    }

});

return(
    <div>
        <p>Time : {date.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
    </div>
)

}

export default DateTime;
```

Comment: nvm, I found a workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

nvm, I found a workaround to the problem. Here's the workaround. don't forget to import your javascript file as I did. Happy hacking :)

```js
const clock = document.getElementById('clock');


const dateLocal = 'en-US';
const dateFormat = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};

const clockFn = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const time = now.toLocaleTimeString().split(':').splice(0, 2).join(':');
  const date = now.toLocaleDateString(dateLocal, dateFormat);
  clock.dataset.time = time;
  clock.dataset.date = date;
};


setInterval(() => {
  clockFn();
}, 1000)
clockFn();
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```